# Borders around images in table cells (Swift, iOS >= 14)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have the code below for configuring the content and look of cells in a table view. It works as intended, but I'd like to add a light gray border around the image.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Picture", for: indexPath)
        
        var cellConfig = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()      
        
        let cellImage = UIImage(named: "Flags/" + pictures[indexPath.row])?.resize(withSize: CGSize(width: 50, height: 25))
        
        
        cellConfig.image = cellImage
        
        cellConfig.text = countries[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.contentConfiguration = cellConfig
        
        return cell
    }
```

Elsewhere in the code, I'm able to do that using something like

```
flag.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
flag.layer.borderWidth = 1
```

where flag is a UIImageView. However, I cannot figure out how to do something analogous inside a cell. I've tried playing with cell.backgroundConfiguration, but that affects the entire cell, not just the image. Can anyone give me a hint? Thanks in advance

Comment: What I do is supply a custom content configuration class that creates a custom content view. See case 2 of https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/d4c84b61b9634f206cb1a5df73a8c16b6200820d/iOS14bookExamples/bk2ch08p409TableContentConfiguration/TableContentConfiguration/ViewController.swift

Comment: Let me see if I understand what you are suggesting: editing (or better yet, subclassing) your MyContentView class so as to have a UIImageView as a subview, with its layer properties appropriately set to get the desired border. Is that it?

Comment: Right. The default configuration creates and lays out the content view in a default way. By making your own configuration you get to create and lay out the content view your way. Of course, this assumes you want to keep using content configurations. You could just do this the old way and configure the cell as a UITableViewCell subclass.

Comment: I think I'd rather go for the new way; Apple has already nuked the imageView property, who knows what they're going to do next.

Comment: "Apple has already nuked the imageView property" But since you won't be using that property you won't encounter any issue (if you just provide a cell subclass as I'm suggesting).

Comment: Of course. What I mean is that when Apple introduces a new way of doing things, it may only a be matter of time  until it becomes the only possibility.

Comment: Haha, I know what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is a content configuration? It's a way of constructing a view (a "content view"), along with a repertoire of ways to modify that view, as communicated by way of a "configuration state":

```
public protocol UIContentConfiguration {
    func makeContentView() -> UIView & UIContentView
    func updated(for state: UIConfigurationState) -> Self
}
```

You have bought into an existing content configuration. Therefore the views you get are the views you get (one label and one image view), and the modifications you can make are the modifications you can make (as defined by the configuration state).

If you want to change that, you have to provide a custom object somewhere in that architecture. You can make up your own content configuration which draws the cell contents and puts the border around the image view. Alternatively, you might be able to get away with modifying the state, as explained in the documentation of UIConfigurationStateCustomKey. But the point is, you can't *just* use the *default* configuration and expect to be able to modify the subviews directly, because (as you've discovered) you've no *access* to the subviews.

Comment: Good answer; I have no argument with what you are saying, as it describes things as they are. However, in my view, not having access to the subviews points to what I would regard as a failing of the architecture, in that it forces you to do a lot of heavy lifting to achieve a relatively trivial goal. I'm holding back a bit on marking the question as answered, in the hope that maybe someone will offer a clever, "lighter" workaround.

Comment: It _would_ be a trivial goal if you were not using configurations. But you are using them, so you are confined to what the configuration lets you do. Pick one or the other. — I mean, look, you could cheat and try to _find_ the image view somehow. But, yecch.

Comment: Yes, I can choose -- for the time being. As I pointed out earlier, when Apple starts pushing something, you see where things are heading, and that has to be factored in.  OTOH, your comment just gave me an idea I want to explore -- thank you.

Comment: @Torrontés I'd be curious to hear how you actually ended upon going on this one.

Comment: For now, I just subclassed the cell. I tried looking into getting a hold of the subviews, but I did not get anywhere. Eventually, I will move over to the new architecture, but it is a lower priority. Thanks for asking.